# IndexError: bytearray index out of range? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mavlink

I tried to send commands through Pymavlink #233

But as I input the data. The data is in binary.

It comes with this error. Does anyone know what the following error means?

```
return MAVLink_message.pack(self, mav, 35, struct.pack(’<BB180B’, self.flags, self.len, self.data[0], self.data[1], self.data[2], self.data[3], self.data[4], self.data[5], self.data[6], self.data[7], self.data[8], self.data[9], self.data[10], self.data[11], self.data[12], self.data[13], self.data[14], self.data[15], self.data[16], self.data[17], self.data[18], self.data[19], self.data[20], self.data[21], self.data[22], self.data[23], self.data[24], self.data[25], self.data[26], self.data[27], self.data[28], self.data[29], self.data[30], self.data[31], self.data[32], self.data[33], self.data[34], self.data[35], self.data[36], self.data[37], self.data[38], self.data[39], self.data[40], self.data[41], self.data[42], self.data[43], self.data[44], self.data[45], self.data[46], self.data[47], self.data[48], self.data[49], self.data[50], self.data[51], self.data[52], self.data[53], self.data[54], self.data[55], self.data[56], self.data[57], self.data[58], self.data[59], self.data[60], self.data[61], self.data[62], self.data[63], self.data[64], self.data[65], self.data[66], self.data[67], self.data[68], self.data[69], self.data[70], self.data[71], self.data[72], self.data[73], self.data[74], self.data[75], self.data[76], self.data[77], self.data[78], self.data[79], self.data[80], self.data[81], self.data[82], self.data[83], self.data[84], self.data[85], self.data[86], self.data[87], self.data[88], self.data[89], self.data[90], self.data[91], self.data[92], self.data[93], self.data[94], self.data[95], self.data[96], self.data[97], self.data[98], self.data[99], self.data[100], self.data[101], self.data[102], self.data[103], self.data[104], self.data[105], self.data[106], self.data[107], self.data[108], self.data[109], self.data[110], self.data[111], self.data[112], self.data[113], self.data[114], self.data[115], self.data[116], self.data[117], self.data[118], self.data[119], self.data[120], self.data[121], self.data[122], self.data[123], self.data[124], self.data[125], self.data[126], self.data[127], self.data[128], self.data[129], self.data[130], self.data[131], self.data[132], self.data[133], self.data[134], self.data[135], self.data[136], self.data[137], self.data[138], self.data[139], self.data[140], self.data[141], self.data[142], self.data[143], self.data[144], self.data[145], self.data[146], self.data[147], self.data[148], self.data[149], self.data[150], self.data[151], self.data[152], self.data[153], self.data[154], self.data[155], self.data[156], self.data[157], self.data[158], self.data[159], self.data[160], self.data[161], self.data[162], self.data[163], self.data[164], self.data[165], self.data[166], self.data[167], self.data[168], self.data[169], self.data[170], self.data[171], self.data[172], self.data[173], self.data[174], self.data[175], self.data[176], self.data[177], self.data[178], self.data[179]), force_mavlink1=force_mavlink1)
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

The data which printed out when print(bytearray(data))

```
bytearray(b’\x14\x15\x01@\xc0\x8d\t\x98\x82\xe4\x00\x00\x01K\xe7\xd7)\xa9d\x92\xc8\n\x00\x10\xaa\xa6:\xa3\xac\xca\x81\\x00\x80\x96\xc4\x00\x00\x0cD\xc3R\x88n\xf4\x82T\x00\x00`$\x00\xfe’)
```

My code is as follows:

```
data = bytearray(buf)
lng = len(data)
the_connection.mav.gps_rtcm_data_send(flags, lng, data)
```

Comment: does `data` contain 180 items?

Comment: `len(bytearray(data))` is `52`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting to me maybe I need to fill it up to 180

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, I need to fill up 180bytes but the data only had much lesser bytes. The way I did was fill the entire bytearray with empty items to 180

```
data = list(data)
        buf = bytearray(data)
        lng = len(buf)
        fill = 180 - lng
        buf.extend(bytearray(fill))
        the_connection.mav.gps_rtcm_data_send(flags, lng, buf)
```

Seems to not return any error.